# OpenCV: Optmized way for Finding Peak Location on x-axis

Tags: .net, opencv, image-processing

Location of Peak (on x axis) in the following image is to be detected

[image]

If the image were vertical I would have applied CvMinMax to locate the peak. But since here it is horizontal I am facing difficulty.  Is there a way I can use CvMinMax to locate this peak? (I do not want to rotate the image)

As the last option I have to search each column, which I do not want to do as this will be very expensive. Is there any optimised way to search such peaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fast method:

1. Get the sum of all the columns at once using `cv.Reduce`. This gives us a vector of columns sums.
2. Threshold this vector so it is effectively binary.
3. Flip the image on the vertical axis.
4. Use `cv.MinMaxLoc`, which reports the location of the first minimum and the first maximum it finds from the left (as the image is binary it gives us the first non zero value).
5. Calculate the column position.

Here it is implemented in python, it should be very easy to convert to C as they are all builtin opencv functions.

```
def find_left_max4(im):
    sums = cv.CreateImage((im.width, 1), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    cv.Reduce(im, sums, dim=0, op=cv.CV_REDUCE_SUM)
    cv.Threshold(sums, sums,200, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
    cv.Flip(sums, flipMode=1)
    return sums.width - cv.MinMaxLoc(sums)[3][0] - 1

im = cv.LoadImage('zfUHp.jpg',cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
print find_right_max4(im)
#Output:
324
```

I don't think you're going to be able to beat this approach for speed. For my slow computer it clocks in at 54 µs (ten times faster than my previous post).

Comment: Why not do this in C/C++? Is it that Python will be faster? (I do not have any experience working on python)

Comment: @gpuguy - You can convert this to C, if you like, (I don't know C). The code is very simple and the main operation `cv.Sum(cv.GetCol(im, x))` is native to opencv (so is in C anyhow), so there is likely to be very little speed difference between this and C. :)

Comment: Does the flipping involve any kind of rounding-off? just like rounding-off happens when we rotate an image? If yes then I might not get correct result. Could you please verify my understanding. Just update this in you answer.

Comment: @gpuguy - Flipping makes a mirror image of the 1-D vector, and there is no rounding. I'll add more explaination tomorrow when I have time. The main thing that can lead to a wrong answer is noise in your image (you have some in this image, so I set the threshold to 200).

Answer (score 0):

Access the pixels of the image row by row and use simple distance approach. I hope you don't need the code for that too.